# Use ng-controller inside angular templates

Tags: angularjs

I am passing `ng-controller` attribute in my `ng-template` script tag as,

`<script type="text/ng-template"  id="dirTemplate.html"  ng-controller="tmplCtrl">`.

But the variables inside controller scope are not available inside the template.

Jsfiddle for the above code is available at, http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21925/

Comment: @Arkantos, that is an incorrect statement. `ng-include` works with both external URLs to templates as well as those defined within script tags like in the question.  Please see the docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script

Comment: There is a problem with your fiddle too, looks like JSFiddle automatically creates top level `body` tag with `ng-app="myApp"`.

Comment: @jusopi.. you're correct. My mistake :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it one of 2 ways but not how you're currently doing it.

#### add the `ng-controller` to the div consuming the `ng-include`

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <script type="text/ng-template"  id="dirTemplate.html">
     {{tmplValue}}
  </script>

  <span ng-include="'dirTemplate.html'" ng-controller="tmplCtrl"></span>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21927/

**OR**

#### add the ng-controller in a nested div inside your template

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <script type="text/ng-template"  id="dirTemplate.html">
      <div ng-controller="tmplCtrl">{{tmplValue}}</div>
    </script>

    <span ng-include="'dirTemplate.html'"></span>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pkpbwee9/1/